# How To Get BirthDate or Gender In Google Plus Login Ionic3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

How To Get BirthDate  or Gender In Google Plus Login Ionic3 ?

```
 GPLogin(){  
      this.googlePlus.login({'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'})
      .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      alert("success "+JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      alert("error "+JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the google plus cordova plugin [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/README.md).

If You search for `scope`, You will find what You are looking for. You need to add Your required `scopes` to be able to get the users profile data.

A complete list of all google scopes can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

In Your case it should be the `Google People API, v1`.

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read` = View your complete date of birth.

But beware of the [known bugs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/search?q=scope&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) related to the scope feature.